# Organizng SVN repositories in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

in the SVN REPO perspective I check out repos from a couple of places.
then I go to Java perspective and in the package explorer it is showing all of them but they are not well organized, I like it to see them in the same hierarchy that I see in SVN Repo hierarchy, each project within its own folder...how can I set this?